# How do I make Panel always transparent like the Dock in GNOME 3?

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, panel, transparency

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10. I want the Panel to be always transparent instead of dynamic transparency.

Answer (score 4):

You may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Dynamic Panel Transparency](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1011/dynamic-panel-transparency/) to achieve this.

1. Install the extension from the link above.
2. Reload the page. A settings icon should appear.
3. Click on the settings icon. A window should pop up.
4. Go to the "*Background*" tab and "Enable custom opacity".
5. Set low values for both "Maximized Opacity" and "Unmaximized Opacity".
   [image]

**Note:** You may have to restart the shell/session to see the change. In an Xorg session press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>, then type `r` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. In a default Wayland session log out and log in again.

---

<sub>Tested in an Xorg session, but not in a Wayland session.</sub>

Comment: Have you tested this process? I tried to answer this question, but doesn't worked for me, transparency is only partial as Ubuntu Extension override some transparency level.

Comment: @olivierb2 I tested in an Xorg session, but *not* in a Wayland session. works fine in Xorg. Have you logged out and log in again?

Comment: Okay, I was trying under Wayland only, maybe this is why.

Comment: @olivierb2 I see. I have added a caveat to my answer.

Comment: The extension works, but there's still an unwanted behavior.  When window is maximized - half of the top panel is filled with colour and only the upper part is transparent. Any way to get rid of it?

Comment: @Val That's a colour gradient effect, pretty sure can be fixed by tweaking the shell theme css. Please consider asking a new question.