# GNOME 17.10 Panel is transparent if app is not full screen

Tags: 17.10, panel, gnome-shell

It seems that in GNOME 17.10 they've changed the operation of the Panel. (I'm using Xorg, not Wayland).

If I view the desktop, the top panel is transparent. If I view an application or Nautilus window *not* in full screen mode, the Panel is transparent, however, if I view an application or Nautilus window in full screen mode, the Panel is black.

I believe that this behavior is different than GNOME 17.04, where I believe that the Panel was always black (not transparent). Am I correct?

In 17.10, is there a way to make the top panel always show as black (non transparent)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic transparency of the top bar is a feature of GNOME shell version 3.26 (the one shipped with Ubuntu 17.10).

You may try one of the following to disable this feature:

- Change the shell theme to one which overrides this dynamic transparency feature and makes the top bar always opaque.
  [GNOME-LOOK.ORG](https://www.opendesktop.org/s/Gnome) is a good place to find various themes.
- Use "[Dynamic Panel Transparency](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1011/dynamic-panel-transparency/)" extension and set 100% for both "Maximized Opacity" and "Unmaximized Opacity".
  See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/975355/480481) to this question for reference: [How do I make top bar always transparent like Ubuntu dock in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975343/how-do-i-make-top-bar-always-transparent-like-ubuntu-dock-in-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: Excellent! I used the "Dynamic Panel Transparency" option. Thanks again!

Comment: Feature!! Looks like a bug to me