# How to keep GNOME panel transparent even when app is maximized in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome-shell, desktop-background, transparency, statusbar

I am using GNOME's "Dash-to-panel" extension for shifting status bar to the top and same for the transparency.

In Desktop mode, the transparency is there on status bar

[image: screenshot, desktop mode]

However, Status Bar Transparency does not persist when any app is opened in maximized mode

[image: screenshot, maximized mode]

Is there any way to keep the transparency in maximized mode?

**Update:**

As per this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/975355/975233), I tried 
using Dynamic-Panel-Transparency but after reboot it is showing an error and did not work as well:

[image]

It says "Error Loading Extension".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make Panel always transparent like the Dock in GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975343/how-do-i-make-panel-always-transparent-like-the-dock-in-gnome-3)

Comment: @pomsky Edited the question; kindly check the update.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with that extension. So, I went to the source of the problem.

The steps I took:

1. Open the terminal.
2. Navigate to `ubuntu.css`.

   ```
   cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme
   ```
3. For security I copied `ubuntu.css`.

   ```
   sudo cp ubuntu.css ubuntu_css.txt
   ```

   just in case I screwed up the file.
4. Open `ubuntu.css` in an editor.

   ```
   sudo vi ubuntu.css
   ```
5. Search document for panel.solid until you should see `/* panel color */`.

   ```css
   /* panel color */
   #panel.solid {
   background-gradient-direction: vertical;
   background-gradient-start: #58554d;
   background-gradient-end: #3f3e39;      
   text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
   }
   ```
6. For security I commented out `background-gradient-` css options by using `/* */` so that I could keep the original code.
7. Add a new line and typed:

   ```css
   background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   ```
8. Save the file and restart the computer.

The completed code looks like this:

```css
#panel.solid {
 /* background-gradient-direction: vertical;
  background-gradient-start: #58554d;
  background-gradient-end: #3f3e39; */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

Comment: I tried what you have answered. but it changed to dark black it seems. Could it be the color combination you put in rgba function ain't for transparency ?